Should JSON naming standards require renaming everything from database result?
I use  camelCase as a JSON naming convention for keys (as do many others e.g. Google). This is fine if I am creating a new object to be send to the client as JSON.
However some data comes from the database which returns a record with hundreds of key:value pairs. These are then sent to the client like return res.status(200).json(DBData);
The records from the database come out all in lowercase. So I end up with:
{
   userid: 1234,
   shortdesc: "I am a bot",
   longdesc: "I am a robot with OS level 1.1",
   addressline1: "5 Belvadier Heights",
   addressline2: "Southampshire"
   towncity: "London"
   ...
}

In order for that to follow the naming convention I would have to write to write a function in the router to rename everything into camelCase manually (because how can you tell it where to change the case?):
 {
    userID: 1234,
    shortDesc: "I am a bot",
    longDesc: "I am a robot with OS level 1.1",
    addressLine1: "5 Belvadier Heights",
    addressLine2: "Southampshire"
    townCity: "London"
    ...
 }

Do I really have to do this or is there a better/different way of doing it? Bearing in mind I have not worked in a team/organisation setting before so don't want to mess things up for anyone.

There are several ways to solve this. If you are using springboot + mybatis. Blow is the config for mybatis in your yml file.


mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:mapper/*.xml
  configuration:
    log-impl: org.apache.ibatis.logging.stdout.StdOutImpl
    map-underscore-to-camel-case: true



Using map-underscore-to-camel-case: true is an effective way to automate the mapping process, saving you the effort of writing additional code to transform the keys.
If you are not using this stack, you can use 'lodash' libary.

Thank you, but there aren't any underscores in the database field names. It comes out as fixedaddress not fixed_address for example.

Hi, welcome. Take the tour, and read how to answer
